# Optimization: Faster compilation

Tags: c, windows, gcc, compilation, linker

Separating a program into header and source files perhaps might benefit in faster compilation if given to a smart compilation manager, which is what I am working on.

Will on theory work:
Creating a thread for each source file and
compiling each source file into object file at once.
Then link those object files together.
It still needs to wait for the source file being the slowest.
This shouldn't be a problem as a simple `n != nSources` counter can be implemented that increments for each .o generated.

I don't think GCC on default does that. When it invokes the assembler
it should parse the files one by one.

Is this a valid approach and how could I optimize compilation time even further?

Comment: Most modern build systems run builds in parallel (e.g. `-j` option to the venerable `make`).

Comment: "When it invokes the assembler it should parse the files one by one." Huh? What do you mean with that?

Comment: @Mat I don't use `makes` though. There is something about them that I find repelling.

Comment: That's a pretty silly attitude. Why? How do you, like, compile things?

Comment: @Lundin Isn't GCC calling a whole set of subprograms to work on the input, one of them being the assembler, that translates the input into lower level semantics

Comment: @Roflcopter4 I use my program to build a command line then I execute it?

Comment: @Corelation That would be the _linker_, which translates the object files into machine code instructions. An assembler is a tool which translates assembler source code to machine code (op codes).

Comment: @Lundin Yes that's what I mean. The linker links the op codes into a binary executable. The linker can also translate it to another object file. Doesn't at all cost need it to be a lib or exe

Comment: @Roflcopter4 IDE:s can generate the make file for you, based on the files you included in the project. Welcome to the 1990s. Not wasting your time on learning some icky linker script language is a perfectly reasonable attitude. Better to focus on actual programming.

Comment: @Lundin that's why I never found composing or editing make for mandatory.  And for what I am doing, which composes command line arguments to GCC, not a make, I still don't find it for mandatory, nor a better approach.

Comment: @Lundin I think you referenced the wrong person here. The OP is the one claiming that using make or anything like it is bad. I'm mostly a little shocked that anyone would think something so silly.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 I don't think he is referencing to the wrong person.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 Nope, read my comment again. Using make is a thing of the dark ages, much like shell scripts, bat files and all the other mumbo jumbo rituals you had to go through in the ancient days of command line compilation.

Comment: @Lundin He might actually like living the old days, despite the self-torture, I just can't seem to figure out why is he expecting the same from me. My choice is to use a RAD environment. To do as much high quality code as possible, not using obfuscations or slow-downs, hence that's what RAD is for.

Comment: @Lundin Nobody writes makefiles by hand. Obviously. Blatantly obviously. Anyone with even the slightest will to have their program be portable, however, will use autoconf or cmake or something similar that will ultimately spit out a makefile. Also, I don't really see how command line anything is a thing of the past. GUI based and command line based computing are both valid and useful for different things.

Comment: @Roflcopter4 The GUI simplifies and speeds-up the process. The underlying process is always a command line. That's why the IDE and what's why the RAD. Also note windows. I don't say I like it, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 2):

All modern (as in post 2000-ish) make's offer this feature. Both GNU make and the various flavours of BSD make will compile source files in separate threads with the -j flag. It just requires that you have a makefile, of course. Ninja also does this by default. It vastly speeds up compilation.

Comment: I can see that you like makes haha.
I make programs to automate everything as well as optimize.
This is my flavor of programming. Why should I bother learning make and work with additional files..

Comment: Why bother learning C when you could write in assembler? Why bother learning assembler when you could very well just write programs in hexadecimal?

Comment: You think using make is easier and I don't think. Also easier not> better. Not a big fan of reuse. Prefer greater control and no copyright problems.

Comment: You don't address my point at all. But even your non-sequitur is silly, and for several reasons. Why is easier not better? Especially when, in this case, you get more control over the output? Why on earth are you not a fan of reusing things? Also, in what universe would BSD make have even the slightest hint of a copyright problem? Furthermore, if you don't like make, why are you planning on making a program that does the same thing?

Comment: I am quite worried about your undying urge to call something "silly".

Comment: Reuse doesn't refer to using make specifically but other utilities as well that might and most probably have copyright requirements. Using such utilities in a professional software isn't always good, let alone with greater control.

Comment: Easier is not better, the same reason quantity is not > quality.
Well, at least for making software. While you might seduce your boss, you will be annoying all the front-end users. So I stand for quality.

Comment: Quality is not duplicating things that have been perfected over 35 years of usage.

Comment: That's true. Like SQlite. But the fact something is 35 years old suggests that there are most probably modern approaches that serve someone's needs more effectively. I am not in particular referencing to make, although it is a valid example.